# laravel 5.4 validation array with keys

Tags: validation, laravel-5

In laravel 5.4 when validation is failed I do like:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
                $errors_list = $validator->messages()->all();
```

and I got array like :

```
[errors_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => The image has already been taken.
        [1] => The is main has already been taken.
    )
```

What I dislike in this output that actuall name of error field is ommitted.

Code

```
echo '<pre>$validator->messages()::'.print_r($validator->messages(),true).'</pre>';
```

has output:

```
$validator->messages()::Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object
(
    [messages:protected] => Array
        (
            [image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The image has already been taken.
                )

            [is_main] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The is main has already been taken.
                )

        )

    [format:protected] => :message
)
```

And I did not find how access to messages data.

I would like to get array like:

```
[errors_list] => Array
        (
            [image] => The image has already been taken.
            [is_main] => The is main has already been taken.
        )
```

Is there is a way to make it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

```
$errors->has('image');
$errors->get(image);

$errors->has('is_main');
$errors->get(is_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky one. The reason it's like that is because there may be multiple validation errors happening at once. However if you only have a single rule per entry:

```
array_combine($validator->messages()->keys(),$validator->messages()->all())
```